# Problem with publishing asp.net to Azure. Database error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, entity-framework, deployment

I have a problem with the application when sharing it on azure. It works fine locally, but when publishing it, the message appears:

*There is already an object named 'Categories' in the database.*

Here is my **Context.cs**

```
namespace Sklep_komputerowy.Models
{
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProductContext() : base("Sklep_komputerowy")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and **category.cs**

```
namespace Sklep_komputerowy.Models
{
   public class Category
   {
       [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
       public int CategoryID { get; set; }

       [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Nazwa")]
       public string CategoryName { get; set; }

       [Display(Name = "Opis")]
       public string Description { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
   }
}
```

The application was created on the basis of the wingtip toys tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/

I have the code-first option selected in the publication profile

I migrated database using commands

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-migration firstMigration
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two option
1.delete Categories table on azure sever
or
2. find the migration that creating categories table and remove it from migration file then deploy again